# Contactform7 with Recaptchav3 not showing badge

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, invisible-recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have updated multiple Wordpress websites that used contactform7 Version 4.9 to the new Version 5.1.1. With this update I had to install the new Google Recaptcha V3. In most cases the update was not a problem and it worked perfectly, however in some websites the Recaptcha Badge (bottom right corner) is not showing in the front-end of the websites...?

I've tried to google it, but I can only find people that want to hide the Badge, but I would like to show the badge ˆˆ. Because the badge is missing in some websites I think there might be something wrong with my configuration. Is there any way to check if the Recaptcha works as intended? Or someone has had similar problems with the badge not showing? Thanks in advance!

> Checked for the grecaptcha-badge class, but there is none
>   Checked if there is any Recaptcha script being loaded, and yes there is (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Ld0k48UAAAAAOZmlXfpn-1e91oDo52sWEwyMBLw&ver=3.0'>)

When updating contactform 7 to version 5.1.1. and implementing Recaptcha V3 keys, the website shows the Google Recaptcha badge in the front-end (bottom-right-corner)

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is just adding the following css

```
.grecaptcha-badge{
    z-index:20;  
}
```

Comment: It also works for angular

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, or the problem why the recpatcha isn't showing. This is because some costum javascript in some websites. A workaround is to install a standard theme and to see if the ReCaptcha shows up. However, i dont know which costum javascript is blocking the ReCaptcha, so my workaround is to install a old version of contact form (<5.0) to be able to use ReCaptcha V2, this one doesn't get blocked by costum javascript.